# asynchronously reading a file in C++

Tags: c++, thread-safety, queue, c++14

I have some file that is larger than the memory available for a single core.  Thus the file itself can't be completely read in all at once.  The file is broken up into sections ("records"), that are used in order.

So I'm interested in something like this:

```
struct GetFile {
    GetFile(string filename, size_t num_records) 
       : filename(filename), num_records(num_records) {}

    unique_ptr<vector<double>> get_next_record() {
    // This should always return a new record, 
    // and throw if there isn't one.  But this 
    // shouldn't FETCH a new record.
        return queued.pop_front();
    }

private:
    queue< unique_ptr<vector<double>>, 
           deque<unique_ptr<vector<double>>> > queued;
}
```

But somewhere in here, there needs to be a condition variable and another thread to populate the queue when it gets low.  Is there a best practice here?  I would like to keep this to C++14 code only, though if there are libraries that do this kind of thing, I'm curious what they are.

Is the unique_ptr the right thing here?  It seems like it is a good way to consume the vectors so they disappear when out of scope, but I'm not positive they are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't seem to be about 'asynchronously' reading a file,
it's much rather about reading a large file.  Consider editing the title accordingly?

From your code, it seems that you don't need random access to your data for processing.  If sequential processing is indeed enough, keep it simple like that:

```
    std::vector<double> get_next_record(std::ifstream& file) {
        // Read a chunk of data, e.g. 1000000 values and return them
    }

    void process(std::ifstream& file) {
        while (file) {
            // Notice: No need for unique_ptr<> or similar
            std::vector<double> chunk = get_next_record(file);
        }
    }
```

If you *do* need random access to your data, you'll need to use
some kind of memory mapping of the file.  Check out memory mapped
files in the boost interprocess library in that case:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess.html

Notice that there's no need to use unique_ptr<> in order to
return vectors from a function.  RVO takes care of that:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization